# Updating attributes to empty type in Enterprise Architect

Tags: c#, attributes, enterprise-architect

I am working in Enterprise Architect C# add-ins. I need to update the type of the attribute. It works fine when attribute type is updated as boolean,long,double etc.

The problem occurs when attribute type needs to be updated as empty. I tried assigning `attribute.type=string.empty` and `attribute.type=""` but still doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried "<none>" (kind of a shot in the dark, but that is what it says when you select nothing as the type of an attribute when using the [...])

Answer (score 0):

If you need type as empty simple add attribute.

```
EA.Element theElement  = Repository.GetTreeSelectedObject();
EA.Attribute attribute = ele.Attributes.AddNew("test","");
attribute.Update();
theElement.Refresh();
```

Its working fine for me or post the code which you tried.
EA also accepts any custom values into it.

Arshad

Comment: Thank you. I am able to add the attribute as type empty. When I update this attribute as type = double ,the new type is taken as double, later when I want to update this attribute's type with empty it is not working.

Comment: @rashmi i tried that too and its working for me. Can you please post your sample code